# C project, why the output don't come out?

Tags: c, while-loop, output

This project should print the number of divisors of a given number as input, but the cycle does not stop, making me enter numbers without stopping.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int a,d,cd;

    printf("Insert a number!\n");

    scanf("%d",&a);

    while(a!=d)
    {
        if (a%d==0) cd=cd+1;

        d=d+1;
    }
    printf("The dividers of %d are %d",a,cd);
}
```

Thank you to everyone, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I've undone your last edit since it makes the question not a question. (it looks like "I have this code: <code that works already> - how can I fix it?"). If you disagree with that, feel free to comment or edit it again. If your code has another problem, that should ideally be a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider this line of code:

```
if (a%d==0) cd=cd+1;
```

is what you should see clearly. you are **trying to divide by 0(d is 0 in first iteration)** which gives undefined no as output for comparison with 0.so in your very first iteration your code crashes.hence initialize variable d with 1

**edit:** it's not necessary that your variable gets 0 on initialization but that's the case here it is.

Comment: This is `C` not java. There is no guarantee that d is initially zero. Besides OP said the code keeps running so it certainly never crashed

Comment: there is no guarantee that d would be zero but due to having zero in it d is causing the problem and that is the reason that op program is not getting any output as i have made the code run for my checking myself. @Smac89

Comment: @SUMITKUMARSINGHDIXIT thank you very much, it works! Also i've added a "cd=cd+1" at the end of the while. Because one of the dividers of a number is the number itself!

Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting that `d` and `cd` start out having the value of 0?  They do not.  You need to explicitly set them.

```
int a;
int d = 0;
int cd = 0;
```

If you don't initialize the variables, they will have random garbage in them.